# Proof of Probability Measure Decomposition

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that all probability measures $\mathbb{P}$ on the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ σ-algebra Borel, can be decomposed as

$$\mathbb{P}=\mu+\nu$$

where $\mu$ is a discrete measure and $\nu$ a diffuse measure.

Can you provide some guidance or steps that I have to follow in order to prove that ?

Comment: K L Chung's book has the details.

Comment: Did you try the Lebesgue decomposition theorem?

Comment: @Idontgetit The Lebesgue Decomposition theorem doesn't talk for an absolute continues plus a diffuse measure decomposition ?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 I wrote you an answer, explaining what I meant :)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Which book exactly ?

Comment: I meant  'A Course in Probability Theory'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:** Recall that if $\mu$ is a measure on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$, then $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is an atom (with respect to $\mu$) if $\mu(A) > 0$ and, for each $B \in \mathcal{A}$ with $B \subseteq A$, we have $\mu(B) \in \{0,\mu(A)\}$.  We say that a measure is atomic if every measurable set of positive measure contains an atom.
According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)), a measure $\mu$ is discrete if it equals a (countable) weighted sum of Dirac measures; while a measure $\nu$ is diffuse if it has no atoms.

Using the metric properties of $\mathbb{R}$, one can show that if $\mu$ is atomic, then $\mu$ is discrete.  This holds more generally whenever $\mu$ is a Borel measure on a Polish (= separable, metric) space (e.g. if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}^{d}$).  (Actually, each atom is "equivalent" to a point.)  We won't need that here, but it's worth thinking about.

**Hint:** To start with, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of atoms of $\mu$ in $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.  Show that if $A$ is an atom, then there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\{x\}) = \mathbb{P}(A)$.  (Use the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$.)  Let $\{x_{n} \, \mid \, n \in J\}$ be the set of all points obtained from atoms in this way, where $J \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ (why?).

Define $\mu = \sum_{n \in J} \mathbb{P}(\{x_{j}\}) \delta_{x_{j}}$ and $\nu = \mathbb{P} - \mu$.  Check that $\mu$ is discrete and $\nu$ is diffuse, and notice that $\mathbb{P} = \mu + \nu$.

Comment: Why is $J$ a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ ??

Comment: Hint: A "sum" of uncountably many positive numbers is always infinite.  See this link for the definition of the "sum" of an arbitrarily indexed "sequence": http://faculty.bard.edu/belk/math461/SumsOverSets.pdf  (I write "sum" because it is actually an integral.)

Answer (score 2):

**Lebesgue's decomposition theorem**

For every two σ-finite signed measures $\mu$  and $\nu$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, there exist two σ-finite signed measures $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$, such that:

- $\nu=\nu_0+\nu_1$
- $\nu_0\ll \mu$ (absolutely continuous)
- $\nu_1 \perp \mu$ (singular)

Moreover, $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$ are uniquely determined by $\nu$ and $\mu$.

Since you have a probability space, any measure is $\sigma$-finite and signed.
Choose $\nu=\mathbb{P}$, let $\mu$ be the point masses of $\mathbb{P}$.
The Lebesgue decomposition theorem gives you $\nu_0$ and $\nu_1$, such that $\nu_0$ only has point masses (discrete measure) and $\nu_1$ has no point masses (diffuse measure, for $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$).